# How to draw repeated random samples without risk of drawing same sample twice in base R?

Tags: r

What's a good way to draw random samples from a population without the risk of drawing the same sample set twice and is also statistically sound? I would like to do this in base R, no packages. I would also like the results to be reproducible.

Would this work:

1. `set.seed(1)`  #this seed is arbitrarily chosen
2. randomly sample 1000 numbers from `set.seed(1)` to create a vector (named
   `data100numbers`) with 1000 random seeds
3. feed the 1000 random numbers into a loop that's something like this:

---

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
    x = data100numbers[i]
    set.seed(x)
    index <- sample(1:nrow(data),round(nrow(data))*2/3)
    #etc...more code that does stuff once I draw my random sample
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: How many rows of data do you have? Are you afraid of exceeding the period of the RNG?

Comment: Are you talking about avoiding drawing the same *sample set* twice, or the same *sample point* twice? If you're trying to avoid sampling the same point twice, just use `sample` with `replace = FALSE`.

Comment: i'm trying to avoid drawing the same sample set twice.  I've looked at a few ways to do it but seems like that risk is there to draw the same sample set.  The examples I've seen only either draw a bunch of samples, or draw samples without drawing the same sample point twice.

Comment: How many rows does data have? Also, does the order of your draws matter (e.g., do you consider (1,2,3) and (3,2,1) to be the same)? Giving some context on why repeated draws are bad also might be helpful.. Such a sampling scheme makes your samples dependent and it may also be problem.

Comment: I'm trying to split my data into training and validation.  I have roughly 1000 data points and plan on doing about a 70/30 split.  What I want to do is draw 700 data points 1000 times without any risk of the same sample set occurring.  I would like to do this with base R.